# Django rest framework parallel execution of many=True field data

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework, python-multiprocessing

I have a serializer, in that I've overridden the `validate` method.

```
class ProcessItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=63)
    # Few more fields

    def validate(self, data):
        # few data processing and HTTP calls
        return data
```

I have another serializer which use above serializer as `many=True` field

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    items = ProcessItemSerializer(many=True)
```

If I pass a list of item data to `DataSerializer` it will process one by one each item. thats desirable!

but if length of items is more than 100 it takes much time. what I want is to execute set of 20-20 items parallel using python-multiprocess so that I can reduce the overall time.

how can I do this in DRF. what method do I have to override?

Comment: This isn't a trivial task, at all. Can you explain exactly what type of validation you are doing? It will be much easier to optimize that rather than to attempt any form of distributed processing.

Comment: Using multiprocessing for IO bound is not a good idea, you should use coroutine (gevent)

Comment: as @hadi correctly mentioned, your validation is I/O-bound, so multiprocessing isn't going to help you much.

Comment: @hadi true, I/O bound but internally that are not dependent . I mean item[0] is not dependent on item[1] at all.

Comment: If your data does not change frequently, use caching, http cache server

Comment: okay: take a look at [django-celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html), I hope this can help you

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to process in parallel by overriding [`ListSerializer`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer) and more specifically the [`to_internal_value`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L607) method.

So it should look something like:

```
class ProcessItemListSerializer(ListSerializer):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        ....


class ProcessItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    field1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=63)
    # Few more fields
    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = ProcessItemListSerializer

    def validate(self, data):
        # few data processing and HTTP calls
        return data
```

In `to_internal_value`, you may need to copy the beginning of the code till [`for item in data:`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L634) and there construct the validation by chunks...